# Can't play vid on Samsung stock player

Tags: android, video, android-intent, samsung-mobile, start-activity

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
Uri uriforintent = Uri.parse(uri);
i.setDataAndType(uriforintent, "video/*");
//startActivity(i);
startActivityForResult(i, 0);
```

The video is a local file **playable** by Samsung stock vid player **if I call *startActivity()***.
It only fails to play with *startActivityForResult()*.

Following errors were logged:

```
06-02 19:07:12.742: E/MediaPlayer(23993): Error (1,-2147483648)
06-02 19:07:12.742: E/MoviePlaybackService(23993): TouchPlayer :: mErrorListener = 1<<<<<<<<<<<<
06-02 19:07:12.742: D/MoviePlayer(23993): onSvcNotification - action : 104
06-02 19:07:12.742: E/MoviePlayer(23993): createErrorDialog(action, intent). action = 104
```

Does anyone faces the same issue with **Samsung stock video player**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `ACTION_VIEW` is not designed for use with `startActivityForResult()`, and since you will not actually get a result anyway, just use `startActivity()`.

Comment: follow up question. what do you suggest me to do if I need to do something after the video is stopped? Must I implement my own player?

Comment: @alexhkleung: Yes, you must implement your own player, whether using `VideoView` or the combination of `MediaPlayer` and a surface (`TextureView`, or `SurfaceView` if you need to support older devices).

Comment: @alexhkleung : "Must I implement my own player?". Yes, that's basically your only option. If you use any 3rd-party app to do anything there is no guarantee you'll ever know when it has completed. If your video file format is supported by `MediaPlayer` then I'd suggest you look into implementing a player with that. You can at least get notifications of 'completion' of playback (for example). You can also youse various methods to tell if a user has paused / stopped playback etc.